# Is it true that if $|f(z)| \leq p(|z|)$ for some polynomial $p$, then $f(z)$ is a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, entire-functions

Suppose that we have an entire function $f(z)$, which is bounded by: $$|f(z)|\leq p(|z|)$$ for some polynomial $p(z)$. Is it possible to prove that $f(z)$ is a polynomial? I know that it is easy for $p(z)=z^n$, but what if we take some general polynomial? Also is there something we can deduce if $p$ is some other entire function?

Comment: For $|z|$ large, we have $p(|z|) \le a |z|^n$.

Comment: The "also" part only makes sense when $p$ sends $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$ to $\Bbb R_{\geq 0}$.

Comment: For a slight variation: if $f, p$ are entire functions such that $|f(z)| \leq |p(z)|$ for all $z$, then it is easy to see that the quotient $f/p$ is again entire, and bounded, which means that $f(z) = \lambda p(z)$ for some constant $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| \leq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Use $p(z)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_n z^n \implies p(|z|) \leq K|z|^n \ \forall |z|>R$ for some R, $K=\sum |a_n|$ for general polynomial.

Comment: And how do we finish it? I know in the case when $p(z)=z^n$ we say that $f/p$ has removable singularity at 0 so it can be continued to 0 in order to apply Liouville theorem.  But here you have that inequality for $|z|>R$.